# Cant create window using CreateWindowEx function

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I cant create the window using code below although i get no error in compilation.Only a window with title of my project name appears.I also set `hwnd=NULL` after `CreateWindowEx` invocation to see whether `MessageBox` works but it does not work too.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <StdAfx.h>

const char* myClassName="myWindowsClassName";

//The window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd , UINT msg , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam){
switch(msg){
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow( hwnd );
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd , msg , wParam , lParam );
}
return 0;
  }

 //Registering window

 int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance , HINSTANCE hPrevInstance ,    LPSTR lPCmdLine , int nCmdShow ){
 WNDCLASSEX wc;
 HWND hwnd;
 MSG msg;

wc.cbSize=sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
wc.style=0;
wc.lpfnWndProc= WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra=0;
wc.hInstance=hInstance;
wc.hIcon=LoadIcon( NULL , IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL , IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground= (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName=NULL;
wc.lpszClassName= (LPCWSTR) myClassName;
wc.hIconSm=LoadIcon( NULL , IDI_APPLICATION );

if( !RegisterClassEx( &wc ) ){
    MessageBox( NULL ,L"Window registeration failed" ,L"Error!" , MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK );
    return 0;
}



  //Creating the window
  hwnd=CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE , (LPCWSTR)myClassName , L"The title of my window" , WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW , CW_USEDEFAULT , CW_USEDEFAULT, 320 , 240 , NULL , NULL , hInstance , NULL );
  hwnd=NULL;
  if( hwnd==NULL ){
MessageBox( NULL ,L"Window creation failed",L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK );
return 0;
 }
  ShowWindow ( hwnd , nCmdShow );
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);


 // Step 3: The Message Loop
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return msg.wParam;

 }
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: _"I cant create the window"_ and _"a window with title of my project name appears"_. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Even if i remove the code from `hwnd=CreareWindowEx` to the end that window with title of my project appears so i realized my window wasnt created at all

Comment: @Johnny Mopp i fixed errors using the answer and rebuilt it as you said.It worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode vs ANSI mismatch?

`myClassName` is `char*` but you cast it to `(LPCWSTR)`. If you are compiling as Unicode (and you should) then you should define the class name as `const WCHAR* myClassName=L"myWindowsClassName";` and remove the casts (or use `const_cast<LPTSTR>()`.

You also fail to initialize `.cbWndExtra`. Change `WNDCLASSEX wc;` to `WNDCLASSEX wc = {};`

You should perform better error checking to diagnose failures. Check on MSDN to see if a function sets the last error when it fails. If it does, call `GetLastError()` after the function fails.